# Deprecation Warning Use DataSource instead of MLDataTable when initializing in Create ML

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, createml

I am running the following code in Xcode 14.3 Playgrounds. I am using macOS Ventura 13.1.

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "all-data", withExtension: "csv")!
let dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)


let (classifierEvaluationTable, classifierTrainingTable) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.20, seed: 5)

let classifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: classifierTrainingTable, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment")
```

I get the following warning:

```
'init(trainingData:textColumn:labelColumn:parameters:)' was deprecated in macOS 13.0: Use DataSource instead of MLDataTable when initializing.
```

The problem is that there is no documentation on how to create DataFrame or DataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling some time on that case. We can use DataFrame, so the warnings will avoid. At this time it's not deprecated.

There is an example, what I found how to rewrite this.

Previous version:

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "all-data", withExtension: "csv")!
let dataTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: csvFile)


let (classifierEvaluationTable, classifierTrainingTable) = dataTable.randomSplit(by: 0.20, seed: 5)

let classifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: classifierTrainingTable, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment")
```

Updated:

additionally add this

`import TabularData`

```
let csvFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "all-data", withExtension: "csv")!
let dataFrame = DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: csvFile)

let (classifierEvaluationSlice, classifierTrainingSlice) = dataFrame.split(by: 0.20, seed: 5)


let classifierTrainingFrame = DataFrame(classifierTrainingSlice)
let classifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: classifierEvaluationFrame, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment"))
```

Additionally we can compare & print metrics and save file:

```
let classifierEvaluationFrame = DataFrame(classifierEvaluationSlice)
let metrics = model.evaluation(on: classifierEvaluationFrame, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "sentiment"))
print(metrics.classificationError)
    
let modelPath = URL(filePath: "YourPath/YourModelName.mlmodel")
try model.write(to: modelPath)
```

Comment: Also I tried to do same with MLTextClassifier.DataSource but failed, it is really weird at moment. So if someone tried this before, share your solutions please. Thanks :)